# Como chamar um método dentro de um System.out.println?

Tags: java, método

Tem como chamar um método dentro de um `System.out.println(" ");`?

Segue meu código:

```
package ExerciciosReferenciaDeObjetos;

    public class Aluno {
        private String nome;
        private int matricula;
        private float n1,n2,media;




    public void Aluno(String nome, int matricula, float n1, float n2){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.matricula=matricula;
        this.n1=n1;
        this.n2=n2;
    }

    public void  Media(float n1, float n2){
        float Media;
        Media= (n1+n2)/2;
    }


    public void Exibir(){
        System.out.println("Nome:"+this.nome);
        System.out.println("Matrícula:"+this.matricula);
        System.out.println("Nota 1:"+this.n1);
        System.out.println("Nota 2:"+this.n2);
        System.out.println("A média é:"+this.media()); /**no caso estou querendo chamar o método da média dentro do system.out... , mas está dando erro**/ 


    }
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código tem vários erros. Há o nome do método que está declarado como maiúsculo, o que não é ideal e está chamando minúsculo. Ele está recebendo parâmetros que nem são necessários, mas na chamada não os usa. Não retornando um valor e só assim você pode usar esse valor em algum outro lugar. O construtor também está errado. Melhorei mais algumas coisas.

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno("joao", 1, 8f, 6f);
        aluno.exibir();
    }
}

class Aluno {
    private String nome;
    private int matricula;
    private float n1, n2;

    public Aluno(String nome, int matricula, float n1, float n2) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
    }
    
    public float media() {
        return (n1 + n2) / 2;
    }
    
    public void exibir() {
        System.out.println("Nome:" +nome);
        System.out.println("Matrícula:" + matricula);
        System.out.println("Nota 1:" + n1);
        System.out.println("Nota 2:" + n2);
        System.out.println("A média é:" + media());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8fOFVk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sgghisjp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Media.java).

Answer (score 1):

Sim tem mas nesse caso não ira funcionar por que seus metodos estão como void vc teria que colocar os metodos do msm tipo do retorno dele e é clado adicionar um return, vou te mostrar como ficaria a classe media por exemplo

```
public float  Media(float n1, float n2){
float Media;
Media = (n1+n2)/2;
return Media;
   }
```

Comment: depois que eu tirei o void ele esta dando esse erro na linha que eu chamo a 
média: "the method media()  is undefined for the type Aluno "

Comment: @italovinicius já dei uma resposta completa e mostrei funcionando, dá uma olhada.